# Syntax issue in Stream Analytics Query running in Azure: Invalid column name: 'payload'

Tags: azure, iot, azure-stream-analytics, stream-analytics, bigdata

I am having a syntax issue with my stream analytics query. Following is my Stream Analytics query, where i am trying to get following fields from the events:

- Vehicle Id
- Diff of previous and current fuel level (for each
  vehicle),
- Diff of current and previous odometer value (for each
  vehicle).

**NON-WORKING QUERY**

```
SELECT input.vehicleId,
FUEL_DIFF = LAG(input.Payload.FuelLevel) OVER (PARTITION BY vehicleId LIMIT DURATION(minute, 1)) - input.Payload.FuelLevel,
ODO_DIFF = input.Payload.OdometerValue - LAG(input.Payload.OdometerValue) OVER (PARTITION BY input.vehicleId LIMIT DURATION(minute, 1)) 
from input
```

Following is one sample input event on which the above query/job is ran on the series of events:

```
   {
      "IoTDeviceId":"DeviceId_1",
      "MessageId":"03494607-3aaa-4a82-8e2e-149f1261ebbb",
      "Payload":{
         "TimeStamp":"2017-01-23T11:16:02.2019077-08:00",
         "FuelLevel":19.9,
         "OdometerValue":10002
      },
      "Priority":1,
      "Time":"2017-01-23T11:16:02.2019077-08:00",
      "VehicleId":"MyCar_1"
   }
```

Following syntax error is thrown when the Stream Analytics job is ran:

> ***Invalid column name: 'payload'. Column with such name does not exist.***

Ironically, the following query works just fine:

**WORKING QUERY**

```
SELECT input.vehicleId,
FUEL_DIFF = LAG(input.Payload.FuelLevel) OVER (PARTITION BY vehicleId LIMIT DURATION(second, 1)) - input.Payload.FuelLevel
from input
```

The only diffrence between WORKING QUERY and NON-WORKING QUERY is number of LAG constructs used. The NON-WORKING QUERY has two LAG constructs, while WORKING QUERY has just one LAG construct.

*I have referred  Stream Analytics Query Language, they only have basic examples. Also tried looking into multiple blogs. In addition, I have tried using **GetRecordPropertyValue**() function, but no luck. Kindly suggest.*

*Thank you in advance!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a syntax bug indeed. Thank you for reporting - we will fix it in the upcoming updates.

Please consider using this query as a workaround:

```
WITH Step1 AS
(
SELECT vehicleId, Payload.FuelLevel, Payload.OdometerValue
FROM input
)

SELECT vehicleId, 
FUEL_DIFF = LAG(FuelLevel) OVER (PARTITION BY vehicleId LIMIT DURATION(minute, 1)) - FuelLevel,
ODO_DIFF = OdometerValue - LAG(OdometerValue) OVER (PARTITION BY vehicleId LIMIT DURATION(minute, 1)) 
from Step1
```